# SimException during Instant Run Debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, dex, android-instant-run

I've noticed that when I edit one of the class files in my Android project *while debugging*, and then click the debug button again, instant run throws a SimException with the following message:

> Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:
>   local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type
>   com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event[] using a local variable
>   of type java.io.IOException. This is symptomatic of .class
>   transformation tools that ignore local variable information. 1 error;
>   aborting
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex
>   >     process
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

This only happens when I edit one specific class during debugging. It doesn't happen after editing other files. Why?